# Is it possible to determine the correlation direction of two variables using factor loadings?

Tags: correlation

Specifically, I am wondering if you can determine this when each factor explains only one of the variables well.

Here's an illustration of a factor pattern to clarify:

[image: Factor Pattern]

Is it possible to say that variable 1 and variable 3 are positively correlated? If not, what other information would be needed?